# jQuery UI effect() method - what are the options for each effect?

Tags: jquery-ui

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) has an `effect()` method which is demonstrated at: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/
It shows how you can specify various effects such as 'blind', 'fold', etc. For each effect you can also pass in an `options` hash, but I can't find a list of the available options anywhere. What are they?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hate trying to find what I need on the jQuery site. Google always seems to give me what I want though. I think these are the pages you're looking for:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are no options for effects as of now.

Comment: There are definitely options - the documentation shows where you would plug them in. But there is no list of what the options are.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the jqueryui effect options here.  Just click on each effect and scroll to the bottom where the arguments are listed.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/

Answer (score 0):

try this link:

http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/

It has the documentation you are looking for.