# Where can i get JQuery ui specified options?

Tags: jquery-ui

For example, this page:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/

I knew that the show's prototype is: **show( effect, [options], [speed], [callback] )**, and it says "options:A object/hash including specific options for the effect." What are these **specific options**?? I can't find them :-(

Comment: I think this question was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794355/jquery-ui-effect-method-what-are-the-options-for-each-effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can see some examples in the source code on this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#option-options

See this part of the code, for instance:

```
// most effect types need no options passed by default
var options = {};
// some effects have required parameters
if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
    options = { percent: 0 };
} else if ( selectedEffect === "transfer" ) {
    options = { to: "#button", className: "ui-effects-transfer" };
} else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
    options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
}
```